# Chances of not selecting a duplicated from a elements pool

Tags: probability

For example, I have a pool with 100 elements.

- I can randomly get elements from that pool.
- Once I get one, the element is not removed from the pool.
- At some point, I will have 20 unique of those 100 elements.

How can I calculate the chance to get a new one?

Comment: For the first 20 elements, are those known to be unique, or can there be duplicates there?

Comment: @WestonMiller those are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $100 - 20 = 80$ selections that will get you a new element, out of $100$ possible selections. Therefore, the probability is $\frac{80}{100} = \boxed{\frac{4}{5}}$

In general, with $k$ elements already selected out of $n$, there are $n - k$ out of $n$ selections that will get you a new element, for a probability of $\boxed{\frac{n - k}{n}}$